# how to resolve Warning: An error event has already been emitted on the socket?

Tags: c#, node.js, angular

I am creating my first app in Angular following the steps here [https://angular.io/guide/setup-local](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUyd6.jpg) but when I run the app I get the following errors

> (node:4064) Warning: An error event has already been emitted on the
> socket. Please use the destroy method on the socket while handling a
> 'clientError' event. (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where
> the warning was created)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definitive solution is a valid SSL certificate,  a quick solution to serve is as follows.

```
ng serve --ssl
```

Then, we allow to localhost requests because with default flags the browser doesn't allow the request. Open the flag with address bar of the browser.

```
chrome://flags/#allow-insecure-localhost
```

##### Allow invalid certificates for resources loaded from localhost. > Enable > Relaunch.

[image: ssl cert]

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same problem and changed my port to resolve the problem try running

```
ng serve --port 8080
```